# Index MySQL not uses multiple index

Tags: mysql, indexing

ALTER TABLE people ADD INDEX(lastname, firstname);

SELECT id FROM people WHERE firstname='Name';

Why this select not uses index?

Comment: Because it is not the leftmost of the indexed columns - read the docs about it : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Comment: @PaulF why only a comment and not a proper answer?

Comment: @Shadow: in this instance I felt a comment & reference to the documentation was sufficient. I thought the OP should have referred to that in the first instance as it clearly explains what can & can't be done with multi-column indexes.

Comment: @PaulF if all programmers read the manuals, SO would have 10th of the questions it has now :)

Comment: Very true - many of the answers could simply be **RTM!!!** (or **RTFM!!!** depending on how polite the answerer felt). Much of the time it seems less effort to use Google (which I did to get the link) than type out the queries & sit back & wait for someone else to do it.

Comment: Thanks to all of your answers. The first @PaulF comment is clue to my question.

Comment: A [_cookbook on building indexes_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).